# How to unit test POST method

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have problems with testing post method.
In that method AntiForgeryToken is checked and I don't know to how to mock it.
Beside that everythings works.

Here my method I want to test:

```
[HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Id,Name,Manufacturer,CatalogNo")] Device device)
    {
        ValidateRequestHeader(Request);
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(device.Name)||String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(device.Manufacturer)||String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(device.CatalogNo))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Niepoprawne dane");
            return PartialView(device);
        }
        unitOfWork.deviceRepository.Insert(device);
        unitOfWork.Save();
        return Json(new { ok = true, newurl = Url.Action("Index") });
    }
```

I have already mocked:

```
        private IUnitOfWork fakeRepo;
    DeviceController DC;
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        Mock<IUnitOfWork> mock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.deviceRepository.Get(
            It.IsAny<List<Expression<Func<Device, bool>>>>(),
            It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<Device>, IOrderedQueryable<Device>>>(),
            null))
            .Returns(new[] { new Device { Id = 1, Manufacturer = "a", Name = "b", CatalogNo = "x" } });
        mock.Setup(m => m.deviceRepository.Get()).Returns(new[] { new Device { Id = 1, Manufacturer = "a", Name = "b", CatalogNo = "z" } });
        fakeRepo = mock.Object;
        DC = new DeviceController(fakeRepo);
    }
```

But I'dont know how to method testing `AntiforgeryToken` 
here code:

```
public void ValidateRequestHeader(HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        string cookieToken = "";
        string formToken = "";

        if (request.Headers["RequestVerificationToken"] != null)
        {
            string[] tokens = request.Headers["RequestVerificationToken"].Split(':');
            if (tokens.Length == 2)
            {
                cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
                formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
            }
        }
        AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
    }
```

I can't comment out this call testing purpose but this solution seems little ugly.

Can You suggest any edits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to mock `HttpRequestBase` and `AntiForgery`.

> How do you mock them?

You wrap them in your own interfaces exposing the behaviour you need or may need in the very near future. In your production code you provide the real .NET implementations, in your tests, your mocks.

MSDN says `AntiForgery.Validate`

> Validates that input data from an HTML form field comes from the user
>   who submitted the data.

the [signature that takes two string arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj158363%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) returns `void`.

Your mock `IAntiForgeryValidator` would have a `Validate(string, string)` method that also returns void.

```
public interface IAntiForgeryValidator
{
    void Validate(string cookieToken, string formToken);
}

public class AntiForgeryValidator : IAntiForgeryValidator
{
    public void Validate(string cookieToken, string formToken)
    {
        AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
    }
}
```

You can use a call back for void methods and verify that they were called the correct number of times:

```
antiForgeryMock.Setup(m => m.Validate(
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Callback((string cookieToken, string formToken) =>
                            {
                                // call back
                            });

antiForgeryMock.Verify(m => m.Validate(
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());
```

You have another option (cheating) and that is to stub your call to `ValidateRequestHeader()` in `Create()`. This will enable you to test the rest of your code but is not reccomended because the real `ValidateRequestHeader()` could cause trouble in your production code if you leave the method un-tested.

Comment: Thanks. You code will allow me to mock `AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);` but test will be already failed because this line with throw exception:`if (request.Headers["RequestVerificationToken"] != null)`

Comment: That's why you also need to mock `HttpRequestBase`